# Aurelia not receiving json response with fetch client

Tags: javascript, aurelia, fetch-api

I'm trying to use the fetch client to receive a json object that contains a large array.
I can see the promise in the console that contains the value but the when trying to view the data from the response it's an empty object {}.
What am I doing wrong?

```
@inject(Router,HttpClientService)
export class GameMap {

  constructor(router,client) {
    this.client = client.client;
     firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        this.user = user;
        user.getIdToken().then((idtoken) => this.client.configure(config => config.withDefaults(({headers: {'ID-TOKEN': idtoken}})))).then(() => this.requestMap());
      }
    });
  }

  requestMap() {
    this.client.fetch('game').then(response => json(response)).then((data) => console.log(data))
  }

}
```

HttpClientService

```
    export class HttpClientService {

  constructor(){
    this.client = new HttpClient();
    this.client.configure(config => {
      config
        .withBaseUrl('http://localhost:8808/')
        .withInterceptor({
          request(request) {
            console.log(request)
            console.log(`Requesting ${request.method} ${request.url}`);

            return request;
          },
          response(response) {
            console.log(`Received ${response.status} ${response.url}`);
            return response;
          }
        });
    });
  }



}
```

Comment: Try `response.json()` instead of `json(response)`.

Comment: I receive the following error when using that:

Unhandled rejection TypeError: Failed to execute 'json' on 'Response': body stream is locked

Comment: You're depending on `HttpClientService`, not `HttpClient`, so what happens in `HttpClientService.fetch`.

Comment: I've added it to my original question the HttpClient is the aurelia-fetch-client

Comment: maybe you didn't understand what @AshleyGrant. change `    this.client.fetch('game').then(response => json(response)).then((data) => console.log(data))` to `    this.client.fetch('game').then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data))`

Comment: tried it again didn't get the error with .json(), must have done something weird yesterday. thanks!